# Error while trying to launch tomcat.bat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

Hello everybody I'm trying to develop a SOAP based webservice. While trying to launch Tomcat.bat I get the following error:

```
ERROR reading C:\SOAP\jakarta-tomcat-3.2.4\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\web.xml
At org.apache.crimson.parser/P-082 http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd
ERROR reading C:\SOAP\jakarta-tomcat-3.2.4\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\web.xml
java.net.UnknownHostException: java.sun.com
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
```

This is the content of mystartup.bat:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
set TOMCAT_HOME=C:\SOAP\jakarta-tomcat-3.2.4
set CLASSPATH=C:\SOAP\axis-1_4\lib\axis.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\SOAP\javamail-1.2\mail.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\SOAP\javafx-sdk2.0.3\activation.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\SOAP\xerces-1_2_3\xerces.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\SOAP\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18\C:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
%TOMCAT_HOME%\bin\startup.bat
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: like @Colin said, problem with your web.xml, can you post it? And are you being forced to use Tomcat 3.2.4? this version is nearly 10 years old!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the file `C:\SOAP\jakarta-tomcat-3.2.4\webapps\axis\WEB-INF\web.xml`

Check the file exists, check the permissions set on it, check it is valid XML